# myWebSocketSubject.multiplex(..).subscribe().unsubscribe() closes connection, event further observers exists

Tags: websocket, rxjs5

The following code will close the connection, event further observers exists on the myWebSocketSubject:

```
myWebSocketSubject.Observable.webSocket('ws://mysocket');
myWebSocketSubject.subscribe();
myWebSocketSubject.multiplex(..).subscribe().unsubscribe()
// the connection closed now
```

My expectation was, that the connection gets closed with the last unsubscribe() call (and not with the first one).

**Use Case**

If I get it right, with the `multiplex(..)` operator, on create and complete a message is send to the socket, which e.g. allows to un-/subscribe on server side to specific event.

My preferred Web Socket service could therefore look like as below. There exists only one connection, and this single connection provides several streams. On first subscription to the web socket the connection gets created; and with the last unsubscribe call the connection gets closed. For each data-stream a un-/subscribe message is sent once.

I haven't found a solution to use the `WebSocketSubject.multiplex(..)` method...

Preferred Example Web Socket Service

```
export class WebSocketService {
    connection: WebSocketSubject<any>;
    constructor() {
        this.connection = Observable.webSocket<any>(_createConfig())
    }

    dataStream(eventType: string): Observable<WebSocketMessage> {
        return connection.multiplex(
            () => new WebSocketMessage("WebSocket.Subscribe." + eventType),
            () => new WebSocketMessage("WebSocket.Unsubscribe." + eventType),
            message => (message.type == eventType)
        )
        .retry() // reconnect on error and send subscription messages again
        .share(); // send messages on last/fist un-/subscribe on this stream
    }
    // ...
}

export class WebSocketMessage {
    type: string;
    data: any;
    constructor(command: string, data?:any) {
        this.type = command;
        this.data = data || undefined;
    }
}
```

I have written the following test case which fails...

```
it('should able to handle multiple subscriptions', () => {
      const subject = Observable.webSocket(<any>{url: 'ws://mysocket'});
      const sub1 = subject.subscribe();
      const sub2 = subject.subscribe();

      const socket = MockWebSocket.lastSocket;
      socket.open();

      sinon.spy(socket, 'close');

      sub1.unsubscribe();
      // Fails, because the socket gets closed on first unsubscribe
      expect(socket.close).have.not.been.called;

      sub2.unsubscribe();
      expect(socket.close).have.been.called;
    });
```

If I get it right the `share` operator would do the trick. But after using the operator, the multiplex method is not available.

Thanks for any feedback, input, ...!